# In Joshua 15:25 the amount of items in the list is different

Tags: joshua

Recently asked [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/56638/27054).

When looking deeper to the passage, noticed that between NASB and KJV there's a difference in the amount of cities from the list. The difference is in verse 25.

In KJV

> 25 And Hazor, Hadattah, and Kerioth, and Hezron, which is Hazor,

In NASB

> 25 Hazor-hadattah, Kerioth-hezron (that is, Hazor),

What's the reason behind this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many cities are listed in Joshua 15:25?

Joshua 15:25 New King James Version

> Hazor, Hadattah, Kerioth, Hezron (which is Hazor),

Gill considers only two:

> According to the Targum, **two** cities only are here meant, which reads,

```
 "and Hazorhadattah, and Keriothhezron, which is Hazor";
```

> and this reading seems to be right;
> there were three Hazors in this tribe, one in Joshua 15:23, and two more here, which are distinguished; the first is called Hazorhadattah, or **new Hazor**;

Keriothhezron is also called Hazor. The newest one is Hazorhadattah.

> of which Jerom says (e), there is a village at this day called Asor, in the borders of Ashkelon, to the east of it, which fell to the lot of the tribe of Judah; the Scripture makes mention of it, calling: it new Asor, to distinguish it from the old;

Interestingly Judas Iscariot may have come from Kerioth-hezron.

> and Keriothhezron is the same with Hezron, Joshua 15:3; and had also the name of Hezron. From this place Judas Iscariot is thought to have his name, being Ishceriot, a man of Keriot.

Barnes' assessment is similar:

> In this verse are the names of **two** towns only, not of four. Two places bearing the common topographical appellation, Hazor ("enclosure") are here mentioned and distinguished as "Hazor Hadattah" and "Kerioth-Hezron,"